# Ubuntu: What do you call the base directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory

In Ubuntu, how does one refer to the base directory (when speaking to others, looking it up, etc)? Ie, the top-most directory in which 'cd ..' does not do anything?

This directory typically includes /bin, /etc, /lib, /usr, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As on any UNIX-like system, it's called the "[root directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory)" or just `/`.

Note that Ubuntu, like any UNIX-like system does *not* use the backslash `\` character as a directory delimiter, only the forward slash character `/` (referring to a previous version of the question).

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the use of backslash.

Comment: Not to be confused with the superuser (uid 0), which is conventionally also called `root` (and really should have been named something like `admin` instead).

Answer (score 2):

That would be the [root directory.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory)